# What is the name of this theorem about continuous functions?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be continuous on $[x_0,x_1]$ and $a,b$ positive real numbers. Then there exists $\xi \in ~[x_0,x_1]$ such that

$$\frac{a}{a+b} f(x_0) + \frac{b}{a+b}f(x_1) = f(\xi)$$

It is named Cauchy's intermediate value theorem in the lecture notes. That name doesn't appear in English literature.

[image]

Comment: intermediate value theorem, along with intervals being convex.

Comment: It is just the IVT formulated in a different way: denote $\lambda=\frac a{a+b}$ and the statement is saying $\exists\xi$ such that $f(\xi)=\lambda f(x_1)+(1-\lambda)f(x_2)$, which is a convex combination of $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$

Comment: My edit was for typos: You had $x_0 $  & $x_1$ but changed to $x_1$ & $x_2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a tricky way to formulate the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem): instead of saying that $f$ takes in $(x_1,x_2)$ any value between the largest and the smallest of $\{f(x_1),f(x_2)\}$, they say that $f$ takes any convex combination of $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$.

Comment: +1. We have $\min (f(x_1), f(x_2))\le \frac {a}{a+b}f(x_1)+\frac {b}{a+b}f(x_2)\le \max (f(x_1), f(x_2)).$